# Count number of login days for all users

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have a mysql table containing the login time of each user:

```
"eventDate"    "eventTime"              "name"
"2016-02-06"   "2016-02-06 01:01:01"    "nameA"
"2016-02-06"   "2016-02-06 05:04:20"    "nameA"
"2016-02-06"   "2016-02-06 06:01:18"    "nameC"
"2016-02-07"   "2016-02-07 03:04:43"    "nameA"
"2016-02-07"   "2016-02-07 08:09:23"    "nameB"
"2016-02-07"   "2016-02-07 09:09:23"    "nameB"
"2016-02-07"   "2016-02-07 10:09:23"    "nameB"
"2016-02-07"   "2016-02-07 11:09:23"    "nameB"
```

Whenever a user logs in, my server adds a new record into this table.

How can I count the number of login days for all users?

This is my desired result:

```
"name"      "times"
"nameA"     2
"nameB"     1
"nameC"     1
```

If a user logs in multiple times within a day, only 1 of the records is counted.

The following is my plan to solve this problem; but I get stuck in the first step.

Create a temporary view with duplicate dates removed.

```
"eventDate"     "eventTime"     "name"
"2016-02-06"    "2016-02-06 01:01:01"   "nameA"
"2016-02-06"    "2016-02-06 06:01:18"   "nameC"
"2016-02-07"    "2016-02-07 03:04:43"   "nameA"
"2016-02-07"    "2016-02-07 08:09:23"   "nameB"
```

Then I'll be able to do what I want with

`select name, count(name) from myDB.loginTable where eventTime between '2016-02-06 00:00:00' and '2016-02-07 23:59:59' group by name;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just COUNT DISTINCT the time and group it by name:

```
SELECT
    name,
    COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(eventTime)) times
FROM
    login_table
GROUP BY
    name
```

or directly using eventDate column:

```
SELECT
    name,
    COUNT(DISTINCT eventDate) times
FROM
    login_table
GROUP BY
    name
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use a subquery - first get the distinct day \ month \ year for each user, then count the occurrences, like so:

```
SELECT COUNT(name) 
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT DATE(eventTime), name 
    FROM loginTable
) 
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: how about date(eventTime)?

Comment: I just tried your query; but it gives me [[nameA, 3], [nameB, 4], [nameC, 1]], which is not the result I want.

Comment: What is the result you want?

Comment: @Undefined_variable you're absolutely right. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```html
SELECT COUNT(name) FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(eventTime), MONTH(eventTime), DAY(eventTime), name FROM loginTable Where eventDate LIKE '%j%' ) GROUP BY name
```